# Childish logo, sober and professional website: how to?

Tags: website-design

A new customer asked me to design a new website for the company, but the company logo is somehow childish (think comic-sans like fonts). Redesigning the logo is a no-go.

I'm not sure how to make the design work to mix this logo with a sober, corporate design for the website.

**Do you have any ideas or samples of people doing the same?**

Comment: comic-sans-like fonts is potentially OK, but it sounds like you mean "poorly designed and amateur" (??)

Comment: @horatio: yes, amateur but no only that ... it's like .. http://www.trunq.com/images/features/The%20Con%20Ugly%20logo%20300x292_250.jpg

Comment: Idea-gathering brainstorming questions are off-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/785/designing-around-an-awful-logo

Answer (score 2):

The client-has-an-ugly-logo is a common problem. The typical solution is to avoid making it prominent. Build off of or create other visual brand elements. Explore photography and illustration as being primary visuals. Shrink the logo. Move it lower on the page. Make it one color. Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go "sober." You can have a professional-looking site which still has bright or strong colors, which would partner a little better with the "comic sans" kind of logo. I would keep the rest of the text very plain and straightforward: a simple, clean sans-serif; uncluttered menus; lots of white space; photos of happy people (if applicable).

Look at other sites in the company's industry, and see if anyone else has the same problem.